# Destructor not called when an exception is thrown

Tags: c++, algorithm

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
  static int count;
  int id;
public:
  Test() {
    count++;
    id = count;
    cout << "Constructing object number " << id << endl;
    if(id == 4)
       throw 4;
  }
  ~Test() { cout << "Destructing object number " << id << endl; }
};

int Test::count = 0;

int main() {
  try {
    Test array[5];
  } catch(int i) {
    cout << "Caught " << i << endl;
  }
}
```

The code above produces the following output:

```
Constructing object number 1
Constructing object number 2
Constructing object number 3
Constructing object number 4
Destructing object number 3
Destructing object number 2
Destructing object number 1
Caught 4
```

I thought destructors were always called when objects become out of scope, even when exceptions are thrown. Why isn't one of the `Test` instances' destructors called in this case?

Comment: I've edited your question into something more suitable for Stack Overflow. Please follow [the question guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for future reference or your question may be downvoted/closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating an array of `5` `Test` objects but you throw an exception after you create `3` **complete** objects, The exception is thrown while in the constructor of the `4`th object. The construction of the `4`th object is not complete until the closing brace of the constructor is reached.

The stack unwinds calling destructor for those `3` completely constructed objects in the opposite order in which they were created, since the `4`th and `5`th object were never constructed the destructor for them is never called.

The rule for exception is:
Once an exception is thrown destructors for all completely created objects within that scope will be called.
An completely created object is one whose constructor has been called cleanly without any exceptions.

Comment: This [Guru of the Week article (#66)](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm) is especially relevant to this situation.

Comment: off by one -- there's only 3 completely constructed objects, so only 3 destructors are called.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writting the cout statement after id=count as mentioned below:-

```
    id = count;
    cout << "Constructing object number " << id << endl;
    if(id == 4)
    throw 4;
```

you should have written it after the throw statement . That would have given you a better 
picture of what happened . Like this :-

```
Test() {
count++;
id = count;
if(id == 4)
   throw 4;
 cout << "Constructing object number " << id << endl;
     }
```

The o/p would have been :-
          Constructing object number 1
          Constructing object number 2
          Constructing object number 3
          Destructing object number 3
          Destructing object number 2
          Destructing object number 1
          Caught 4